# scrapy login not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to login, but it doesn't even enter the form data.
This is the login part of my code:

```
start_urls = ['https://stmforum.com/amember/login.php']

def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest(url="https://stmforum.com/amember/protect/new-rewrite?f=2&url=/forum/forum.php&host=stmforum.com&ssl=on",
                                formdata={'amember_login': 'username','amember_pass':'password'},
                                callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self,response):
       if "incorrect" in response.body:
               self.logger.error("Login failed")
               return

       elif "Login to your Account" in response.body:
                self.logger.error("Try again")
                return
       else:
                pass
```

This is part of the html code of the website:

```
 <form name="login" method="post" action="/amember/login">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login to your Account</legend>
<div id="recaptcha-row" class="row" style="display: none;" data-recaptcha-theme="light" data-recaptcha-size="normal">
<div class="row">
<div class="element-title">
<div class="element">
<input id="amember-login" name="amember_login" size="15" value="" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Username/Email" type="text"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="element-title">
<div class="element">
<input id="amember-pass" class="am-pass-reveal" name="amember_pass" size="15" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
<span class="am-switch-reveal am-switch-reveal-off" title="Toggle Password Visibility"/>
<label id="am-form-login-remember" class="element-title" for="remember_login">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
</fieldset>
<input name="login_attempt_id" value="1503392293" type="hidden"/>
<input name="amember_redirect_url" value="https://stmforum.com/forum/forum.php" type="hidden"/>
```

And the result of the crawler:

```
[seeker] ERROR: Try again
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

It goes to the after_login elif statement, which means it didn't change the page. Basically says that it doesn't even input the data in the form or it doesn't click login.
I have tried to put in the formdata "Username" and "Password" i also tried to put the id "amember-login" and "amember-pass". 
Also tried to put clickdata={'submit':'commit')
Also tried FormRequest.from_response

With selenium and it worked fine.
i wanted to implement selenium with scrapy but it doesnt work on a server.

Can someone help me?

***UPDATE:***

```
 start_urls = ['https://stmforum.com/amember/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                formdata={'amember_login':'user','amember_pass':'pass'},
                                callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self,response):
       if "incorrect" in response.body:
               self.logger.error("Login failed")
               return

       elif "Login to your Account" in response.body:
                self.logger.error("Try again")
                return
       else:
                return FormRequest(url="https://stmforum.com/forum/",
                                        formdata={'query': 'AdCombo'},
                                        callback=self.parse_page)
```

And the response i get:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stmforum.com/amember/login.php> (referer: None)
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://stmforum.com/amember/member> from <POST https://stmforum.com/amember/login>
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stmforum.com/amember/member> (referer: https://stmforum.com/amember/login.php)
[seeker] ERROR: Try again
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

The 'login_attempt_id' changes for every request made...how do i implement that hidden value in the formdata. or what else can i do?

Comment: Have you tried with [`FormRequest.from_response()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login)?

Comment: Alright, you did. How did you use it? There are some hidden fields so you need to pass them it seems (e.g. `login_attempt_id`). You can compare what your browser sends (using your browser's Dev Tools network panel) and what Scrapy send (for example with `scrapy shell https://stmforum.com/amember/login.php` and then inspecting the result of `FormRequest.from_response()`

Comment: i have tried from_response before and i tried it again. and i did notice the login_attempt_id but it changes for every request....i was looking for a token and i found that id instead.

Comment: `login_attempt_id` changing for every request is the reason why `FormRequest.from_response(response, ...` is recommended, it will pick the value of the hidden field from the response for you, and you only need to pass your login and password.

Answer (score 1):

I check the website and your post is to the wrong URL

```
def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, 
                                formdata={'amember_login': 'username','amember_pass':'password'},
                                callback=self.after_login)
```

The reason is that there are additional hidden variables that need to be sent. That's why you need to use `from_response`

[image: Login hidden variables]

Comment: You need to pass the response to `from_response()` (and the url parameter would be unnecessary)

Comment: @paultrmbrth, thanks for noticing that. Didn't realize not removing that. Updated the answer.

Comment: Still missing `response` as first argument

Comment: I have update the question at the end...i already tried the from_response. and i tried again.  it still doesn't login.

Comment: It doesn't have javascript and login fails fine if JS disabled. Check the `response.body` and see if shows any error. Because else it is hard to debug without more information

Answer (score 1):

I found out that i left the cookies disabled in scrapy settings. Now it works fine.
Thank you very much